# Passing events to another object in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a fullscreen UIScrollView which performs a custom action based on current scroll position. On a layer which is placed above it, but one that is not in the same hierarchy, I have a UIImageView which has a tap gesture recognizer that sends control to a given selector.

My goal would be this:

- If the user taps the UIImageView the tap gesture recognizer runs the selector (this happens)
- If the user swipes up or down elsewhere on the screen the UIScrollView delegate performs its magic (this also happens)
- If the user initiates the swipe (scroll) from the UIImageView, the event is passed to the UIScrollView (this does not happen)

I know this can be achieved if the UIImageView is a subview of UIScrollView, but I want to avoid this as the UIImageView is not meant to scroll with the content of UIScrollView. Is there anyway that I can pass 'scrolling' touch events from UIImageView over to the UIScrollView object while not making it a subview of the scroll view?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` on the image view tap gesture recognizer to pass the scroll view's pan gesture recognizers. This should only activate the tap gesture recognizer if the scroll view's gesture recognizers don't accept the event.

Comment: This does seem like the best solution. But shouldn't this work (it doesn't for some reason)? Is it definitely ok that scrollView is not a superview of imageLogo?
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapLogo = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnLogo:)];
    [tapLogo requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageLogo addGestureRecognizer:tapLogo];

Comment: @Aron Hmm, perhaps it is not possible if the view is not a subview of the scrollview. But why not add it in the hierarchy? You can easily lock it in place with a little math, even when scrolling the scrollview.

Comment: Yeah I think I will do that as I found no way to get around the hierarchy problem. I wanted to avoid moving the object assuming that while the math is easy, it will have performance implications. We'll see...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose the following solution.

AIImageView.m:

```
#import "AIImageView.h"

@implementation AIImageView
{
    NSInteger _cnt;
}

- (id)initWithImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    if ((self = [super initWithImage:image]))
    {
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self
                                                                                     action: @selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        tapGesture.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture];

        _cnt = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIView*) hitTest: (CGPoint) point withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    CGPoint result = [self convertPoint: point toView: self.scrollView];

    _cnt++;

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, result))
    {
        if (_cnt > 2)
        {
            _cnt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return self.scrollView;
        }
    }

    return [super hitTest: point withEvent: event];
}

- (void) handleTapGesture: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"TAP!!!");
}

@end
```

AIImageView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AIImageView : UIImageView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView* scrollView;

@end
```

Create imageView :

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"default_cover.png"];
imageView = [[AIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 100);
imageView.scrollView = self.scrollView;
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

If you will try it you can see that this solution works but not always :). But I believe it can help you.

Comment: This would make the image view not tappable.

Comment: As with the above solution, from my test it seems this only works if the UIImage is a subview of UIScrollView. I was trying to avoid this but I guess it seems inevitable.